# Recurrence relation with given T(0) and T(n) - Big O

Tags: big-o, recurrence

So i need to solve these two recurrences:

```
a) T(0)=1   T(n)=3T(n-1)+1 

b) T(1)=1 T(n)=4T(n/4)+1
```

And i'm quite stuck, i don't even know how to begin this and while searching for an answer i didn't understand how to get to do this step by step.

I'm trying to figure it out right now so if no one answers i'll try to put here how i think it's done.

Comment: This may help: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i think i figured it out thanks to an video on yt.

To those in the future who may need it, i think(if i'm doing it correctly), that this is the easiest way to solve this.

for a)

```
T(0)=1  T(n)=3T(n-1)+1
We make two columns
Solution                              Work
k=1 T(n)=3T(n-1)+1                    T(n-1)=3T(n-2)+1
    T(n)=3[3T(n-2)+1]+1               
k=2     =3^2T(n-2)+2                  T(n-2)=3T(n-3)+1
        =3^2[3T(n-3)+1]+2
k=3     =3^3T(n-3)+3

//Now we see that there's a pattern here so we just have to write it down

n=k     T(n)=3^kT(n-k)+k              T(n)=3^nT(0)+n
                                      T(n)=3^nT*1+n
                                      T(n)=3^n+n ~ O(3^n)
```

for b)

```
T(1)=1  T(n)=4T(n/4)+1
We make two columns
Solution                              Work  
k=1 T(n)=4T(n/4)+1                    n=4^m
        =4T(4^m-1)+1                  T(m-1)=4T(4^m-2)+1
        =4[4T(4^m-2)+1]+1
k=2     =4^2T(4^m-2)+2                T(m-2)=4T(4^m-3)+1
        =4^2[4T(4^m-3)+1]+2
k=3     =4^3T(4^m-3)+3                

//same pattern thing over here

n=k     =4^kT(4^m-k)+k                k=log4(n)
                                      T(m)=4^kT(1)+k
                                      T(n)=4^log4(n)*1+log4(n) ~ O(log4(n))
```